# Perl Regex, get strings between two strings

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl and trying to use Regex to get a piece of string between two tags that I know will be there in that string. I already tried various answers from stackoverflow but none of them seems to be working for me. Here's my example...

The required data is in $info variable out of which I want to get the useful data

```
my $info = "random text i do not want\n|BIRTH PLACE=Boston, MA\n|more unwanted random text";
```

The Useful Data in the above string is `Boston, MA`. I removed the newlines from the string by `$info =~ s/\n//g;`. Now `$info` has this string `"random text i do not want|BIRTH PLACE=Boston, MA|more unwanted random text"`. I thought doing this will help me capture the required data easily.

Please help me in getting the required data. I am sure that the data will always be preceded by `|BIRTH PLACE=` and succeeded by `|`. Everything before and after that is unwanted text. If a question like this is already answered please guide me to it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$info =~ m{\|BIRTH PLACE=(.*?)\|} or die "There is no data in \$info?!";
my $birth_place = $1;
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing everything around it, you could search for `/\|BIRTH PLACE=([^\|]+)\n\|/`, [^\|]+ being one or more of `anything that is not a pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

You know, actually, those newlines might have helped you.  I would have gone for an initial regular expression of:

```
/^\|BIRTH PLACE=(.*)$/m
```

Using the multiline modifer (`m`) to match `^` at the beginning of a line and `$` at the end of it, instead of just matching at the beginning and end of the string.  Heck, you can even get really crazy and match:

```
/(?<=^\|BIRTH PLACE=).+$/m
```

To capture only the information you want, using lookbehind (`(?<= ... )`) to assert that it's the birth place information.

Why curse the string twice when you can do it once?

So, in perl:

```
if ($info =~ m/(?<=^\|BIRTH PLACE=).+$/m) {
    print "Born in $&.\n";
} else {
    print "From parts unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have presumably read this data from a file, which is a bad start. You program should look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile';

my $pob;
while (<$fh>) {
  if (/BIRTH PLACE=(.+)/) {
    $pob = $1;
    last;
  }
}

print $pob;
```

**output**

```
Boston, MA
```