# grep keyword with if-condition

Tags: perl, if-statement, grep

I have an input file with

```
words;
yadda yadda;
keyword 123;
yadda;
```

and I want to simply get the value 123 saved as a variable. I tried a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777044/2622293):

```
my $var;
open(FILE,$data.dat) or die "error on opening $data: $!\n";
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        if (/^keyword/) {
                $var = $1;
                print $line;
                last;
        }
}
close(FILE);
```

This isn't working and gives me following error: `Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./script.pl line 91, <FILE> line 384.` (this occurs for all lines of `<FILE>`)

I found another solution without the if-condition which just states `@string = sort grep /^keyword/,<FILE>;` and works. Can you please explain to me what is happening here?

/edit

Thx for the answers and explanations! What do you think is the better/more elegant way? The grep or the if-condition?

Comment: Your `grep` question is by and large unrelated, in that it doesn't solve this precise problem. One question per question, please; post a separate question if you still want that answered, as you have already accepted an answer here, and thus marked your problem as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following change:

```
if ($line =~ m/^keyword\s+(\d+)/)
```

Explanation: You read into $line, hence $_ which is the default target for match is undefined.
In addition, you'd get another error with $1, because your pattern did not specify a capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` refers to the first capture group, but your regex doesn't contain any capture groups, so it's undefined. Try

```
if ($line =~ /^keyword\s+(-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d*)(?:[Ee]-?(?:\d+|\d*\.\d*))?)/) {
```

Notice also that the regex is being applied to the variable containing the line you just read.

Edit: Updated to cope with numbers in scientific notation. This is a significant additional requirement which you should have specified explicitly in the first place.

Comment: This is just working without the `:`. And numbers like 1e-5 gets cut. I also just noticed this following problem right now.