# regex for floating point numbers

Tags: regex

I have seen many regexes for matching floating point numbers. But I still can't find a perfect solution for my problem.

I have so far come up with this :

```
^[-+]?\d*?(?<=\d)([,.](?>\d*)([eE][-+]?\d+)?)?$
```

which matches all possible float except the ones which begins with . like .4

Here's the  [link](http://rubular.com/r/IPWPZfu67B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can easily put a big `OR` operator.

```
^(?:[-+]?\d*?(?<=\d)([,.](?>\d*)([eE][-+]?\d+)?)?|\.\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I take the following regex to define lots of different styles of numbers:

`(:?-?(?:(?:\d+\.?\d*)|(?:\.\d+))(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?)`

See [older posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969078/matching-all-the-numbers/18119867#18119867) with tests and some explanation.